# Excluding a row that contains a specific value

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to exclude people who have joined a specific group. For example, if some students signed up for an Orchestra club, and I want to retrieve a list of students who did NOT sign up for orchestra, how do I do so?

I am unable to simply do a Group By clause because some students may have joined multiple clubs, and would bypass the Where condition and still show up in the query,
[as shown here.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e9243/7)

I am thinking about using a CASE statement in the SELECT clause to flag the person as '1' if they have joined Orchestra, and '0' if they have not, but I'm struggling to write an aggregate CASE function, which would cause issues from the GROUP BY clause.

Any thoughts on how to flag people with a certain row value?

Apparently my table didn't get saved onto SQLFiddle so you can paste the code below on your own screen:

```
CREATE TABLE activity ( PersonId, Club) as
  select 1, 'Soccer' from dual union
  select 1, 'Orchestra'  from dual union
  select 2, 'Soccer' from dual union
  select 2, 'Chess' from dual union
  select 2, 'Bball'  from dual union
  select 3, 'Orchestra'  from dual union
  select 3, 'Chess' from dual union
  select 3, 'Bball'  from dual union
  select 4, 'Soccer' from dual union
  select 4, 'Bball' from dual union
  select 4, 'Chess'  from dual;
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use the WHERE clause?

Comment: @nbwoodward Yeah the WHERE won't work because a person can join multiple clubs. It will take out the rows that have 'Orchestra' but it won't take the PersonID entirely. I'm testing Sagi's comment right now.

Comment: ah of course... You can also select a list of user ids to kick out (I put in an answer below).

Comment: Is it possible to have "students" who have not joined ANY Club, and therefore they will not be included in this table in the first place? Don't you need to return those as well? If you do, then simply an aggregate query on this table alone has no chance of producing the correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HAVING clause instead of using WHERE, with case expression :

```
HAVING max(case when column = ‘string’ then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Add this after your group by .

Comment: It appears to work! Although this only shows the people who have a row with 'string' (the opposite of what I wanted) I was able to use 'AND NOT' to compensate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about selecting a list of user ids from the activity table and excluding it:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT PersonId FROM activity WHERE Club = 'Orchestra');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
(
  select a.*,  case when Club ='Orchestra' then 1 else 0 end flag
  from activity a 
) where flag =1; --> get some students signed up for an Orchestra club 

  select * from 
(
  select a.*,  case when Club ='Orchestra' then 1 else 0 end flag
  from activity a 
) where flag =0; --> get students not signed up for an Orchestra club
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery to return a list of people to exclude.

```
-- Returns person 2 and 4.
SELECT 
    PersonId
FROM 
    activity
WHERE 
    PersonId NOT IN 
    (
        -- People to exclude.
        SELECT 
            PersonId 
        FROM 
            activity 
        WHERE 
            Club = 'Orchestra'
    )
GROUP BY 
    PersonId
;
```

**EDIT** Removed superfluous distinct in subquery - thanks @mathguy.

Comment: DISTINCT in the subquery is definitely wrong. DISTINCT is an expensive operation, and it doesn't help the NOT IN operation in any way.

Comment: Argh!  Left in by mistake, after testing.